# The implementation of the AES algorithm in openssl cannot correspond

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I am learning AES algorithm. But I found that the implementation of aes in openssl seems to be missing some steps. This is an amazing animation of the aes encryption algorithm(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gP4PqVGudtg).

[image]

I see that the implementation of aes in openssl is mainly two functions.

```
int private_AES_set_encrypt_key(const unsigned char *userKey, const int bits,
                                AES_KEY *key);

void AES_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
                 const AES_KEY *key);
```

The first function is to get the round key that needs to be used for each round.

The second function does normal encryption.

1. The second function does AddRoundKey first. That is the initial round.
2. There are 10 more rounds after that, the last of which has no MixColumns. Below is the code for the nine rounds.

```
    #ifdef FULL_UNROLL
        /* round 1: */
        t0 = Te0[s0 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s1 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s2 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s3 & 0xff] ^ rk[ 4];
        t1 = Te0[s1 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s2 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s3 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s0 & 0xff] ^ rk[ 5];
        t2 = Te0[s2 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s3 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s0 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s1 & 0xff] ^ rk[ 6];
        t3 = Te0[s3 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s0 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s1 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s2 & 0xff] ^ rk[ 7];
        /* round 2: */
        s0 = Te0[t0 >> 24] ^ Te1[(t1 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(t2 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[t3 & 0xff] ^ rk[ 8];
        s1 = Te0[t1 >> 24] ^ Te1[(t2 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(t3 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[t0 & 0xff] ^ rk[ 9];
        s2 = Te0[t2 >> 24] ^ Te1[(t3 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(t0 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[t1 & 0xff] ^ rk[10];
        s3 = Te0[t3 >> 24] ^ Te1[(t0 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(t1 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[t2 & 0xff] ^ rk[11];
        /* round 3: */
        t0 = Te0[s0 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s1 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s2 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s3 & 0xff] ^ rk[12];
        t1 = Te0[s1 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s2 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s3 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s0 & 0xff] ^ rk[13];
        t2 = Te0[s2 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s3 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s0 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s1 & 0xff] ^ rk[14];
        t3 = Te0[s3 >> 24] ^ Te1[(s0 >> 16) & 0xff] ^ Te2[(s1 >>  8) & 0xff] ^ Te3[s2 & 0xff] ^ rk[15];
        /* round 4: */
  ........
```

But according to the previous comment, the meaning of the Te array is as follows:
Why is there no SubBytes, ShiftRows operation?

The last round seems to have also carried out the MixColumn operation? Why is this not in line? Or where am I misunderstanding. thank you very much!

```
    Te0[x] = S [x].[02, 01, 01, 03];
    Te1[x] = S [x].[03, 02, 01, 01];
    Te2[x] = S [x].[01, 03, 02, 01];
    Te3[x] = S [x].[01, 01, 03, 02];
```

Comment: look for "apply last round" in the code ..

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean?